# Why is preview of new 360-views so slow with UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, xamarin.ios

I am building a **Xamarin.iOS** app and have a very odd issue.

From inside the app, users can take multiple photos of objects from different angles. These images are then sent to the server, where a **360-view (panorama)** is generated using [a jQuery plugin, like this chair](http://www.webrotate360.com/products/webrotate-360-product-viewer.aspx). The result is a folder on the server with an .html file, .css and .js files, and the images. Once the upload is complete, server returns a link to the app, which loads the .html page inside a UIWebView.

The problem is that when **a new 360-view** is ready and displayed on the screen, it is **super slow to swipe** left and right. Ultra slow. At the same time, I have **another screen** where users see a list of **all previous 360-views so far**. When one of these **"old" 360-views** is loaded, it is **super quick** and can be swiped easily.

Any ideas why new 360-views previews are so slow?

I am loading the links with a simple:

```
using (var nSUrlRequest = new NSUrlRequest(url))
{
    webView.LoadRequest(nSUrlRequest);
}
```

If I hard-code the url of an old 360-view, preview shows great. If I load the last generated url, preview is super slow.

Answer (score 0):

These are two things that usually result in the slow drag speed when using this jQuery module:

1. Your web server is not requesting the client to cache images, i.e the HTTP header responsible for the client cache (expires or max-age) is not present in the image response. Not sure if that's the case as your other views seem to work fine.
2. Safari on iPhone's iOS has a limit to the combined amount of image data that can be present at once on a given page. Last time I checked, it was around 7-10mb total. Once this limit is reached, Safari starts releasing some images from memory which will result in the very slow drag as these images will be requested from the server again (during the drag).

If Xamarin's web view control uses Safari as an underlying browser engine (I think that's the case), this would be likely the issue. If so, you would need to either reduced the image size or the number of images in the 360 view and/or reduce the image quality to not go beyond this limit when all images are loaded.

Another option that also seems to work is to load the 360 view inside an iframe which doesn't seem to count against the limit in Safari on iOS.